# Remove trailing spaces in string in google apps script

Tags: string, google-apps-script, spaces

I am grouping by "Id" and get the sum of "Total_Weight" in google apps script. This is the result of that computation.

```
res_1 output:

[ { Id: '400 ', Total_Weight: 484308 },
  { Id: '500W', Total_Weight: 13232 } ]
```

After this, I have a if-else clause that loops over the "Id" in above array and does some computation.

```
res_1.forEach((r2,i2)=>{
  if (r2['Id']=="400") {
    var cost = (r2['Total_Weight']/1000)*cost
    NewArray.push([r2['Id'], cost]);
  }
  else if (r2['Id']=="400W") {
    var cost = (r2['Total_Weight']/1000)*cost
    NewArray.push([r2['Id'], cost ]);
  }
}
```

My challenge is in "res_1" the first Id is "400 " (400 followed by a space). Hence, when it comes to the for loop, it does not go into the first if clause. I tried with replacing spaces but that doesnt work as well.

Are there any ways that this could be resolved? Any leads would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `.replace` call on the res_1 output like so:

```js
var res_1_trim = res_1.replace(/\s/g, "")

res_1_trim.forEach((r2,i2)=>{
  if (r2['Id']=="400") {
    var cost = (r2['Total_Weight']/1000)*cost
    NewArray.push([r2['Id'], cost]);
  }
  else if (r2['Id']=="400W") {
    var cost = (r2['Total_Weight']/1000)*cost
    NewArray.push([r2['Id'], cost ]);
  }
}
```

`\s` is a solution to find whitespace and the '`g`' provides a match for instances of whitespace.([.replace documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace))